# Destroy flexslider on mobiles? (with enquire.js)

Tags: resize, flexslider, enquire.js

I'm using http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js for hiding the flexslider on mobiles however the destroy method doesn't seem to work while I resize my browser.

```
/* hide/show slideshow based on viewport size*/     
enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 48em)", {
deferSetup : true,
setup : function() {
    /*home test slideshow slideshow*/
    $(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#home-slider').flexslider({
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: true,
        controlNav: false,
        animation: "fade",
        useCSS: true, 
        });
    });
},
match : function() {
    /* add slider specific class */
    jQuery("#home-slider").addClass("flexslider");
    jQuery("#home-slider ul.slides-init").addClass("slides");
},  
unmatch : function() {
    /* hide slider specific class */
    jQuery("#home-slider").removeClass("flexslider");
    jQuery("#home-slider ul.slides-init").removeClass("slides");    
},
 destroy : function() {
    jQuery("#home-slider").flexslider('destroy');
 }
});
```

Adding/removing classes in match/unmatch functions work ok.

Any insights?

Comment: Flexslider does not have a destroy method at present. It's scheduled for inclusion in the next milestone -- but who knows when it will actually be implemented.